# JSON object retrieving sub values

Tags: java, json

Below is my json object.

```
{
  "result":"ok",
  "data":{  
          "buy":174.03,
          "sell":160.64,
          "timestamp":"2017-12-24T08:46:45.487+00:00"
   }
}
```

I parse it using code and try outputting the value:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonValue);
System.out.println(json.getString("result"));
System.out.println(json.getJSONObject("data").getString("buy"));
```

I can print out the value of result.
But how do I print out the value of data. buy ?
I get error 
       `org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["buy"] not a string.`

Comment: `buy` is a float

Comment: exception message is pretty clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buy` is a double value, not a string. You will have to cast it into a string.

```
System.out.println(json.getJSONObject("data").getDouble("buy").toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

`buy` is not a string because it is not quoted. Try `getDouble("buy")`.

Comment: Ah, the quotes, or in this case, the lack of, makes the difference. Got it.